# Using 那叫 can 叫 be a 量词？

Tags: phrase-meaning

Today I am having trouble getting to grips with 那叫。

Can 叫 be a 量词？

According to zdic.net 叫 can also be used as by:

叫：让;被 [by]。如:你叫雨淋了吗?;叫你猜对了

In each of these 3 examples, is 那叫 a phrase?

Is 那叫 being used in the same way in each example?

```
1. 我那叫一个紧张哦！I was so nervous!
2. 那叫声一直缠绕着我。That sound haunted me.
3. 是啊，她那叫升华。Yes, she ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Can 叫 be a 量词？**

The answer is "no". [Here](http://xh.5156edu.com/page/z7949m2560j18586.html) is a list of Chinese "measured words/classifiers.

**那叫** - that calls/takes as = that essentially is.

1. 我**那叫**一个紧张哦！- **That essentially is** me had a nervous/intense moment.
2. 是啊，她**那叫**升华。- Yes, **that essentially is** her in sublimation.

Note that the second example does not follow the pattern above, it is in the format of **"那 + noun (consisted with 叫) + descriptive phrase"**.

2. 那**叫声**一直缠绕着我. - That **crying sound** continuously bothers me.

Comment: I agree and, to answer Pedrosky's question, would also like to stress that 那叫 is not "being used in the same way in each example". Specifically, #2 is the odd one out: jiaosheng is a bisyllabic noun there, whereas 那叫 in the other sentences is a demonstrative pronoun followed by a verb.